# Extracting single element from array in Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've got a `Dataset<Row>` with the following structure:

```
{"name": "Ben",
"lastHolidayDestination": "Florida",
"holidays": [
    {"destination": "Florida",
     "year": 2020},
    {"destination": "Lille",
     "year": 2019}
]}
```

I want to add a new column `lastHolidayYear` to the root of the Dataset using Spark SQL, populated by finding the `holidays` element that joins onto `lastHolidayDestination` (assume there will only ever be one). So the output Dataset would be:

```
{"name": "Ben",
"lastHolidayDestination": "Florida",
"lastHolidayYear": 2020,
"holidays": [
    {"destination": "Florida",
     "year": 2020},
    {"destination": "Lille",
     "year": 2019}
]}
```

I've been playing around with `dataset.withColumn()` and `when()` (using Java, but Scala/Python answers are fine) but I've got nowhere so far. I really don't want to use a UDF unless I have to. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use SQL to query arrays and objects... These aren't "nested dataframes". For example, select the max of the year column within the [exploded holidays](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/explode-spark-array-and-map-dataframe-column/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. To be clear, I'm specifically looking to select the element based on a value, and not a max/min. My actual use case is more complex (and you're right that in this simplified example it isn't nested so I'll rename it) but I've just baked it down to something simpler here.

Comment: To me, looks like you want to set `lastHolidayYear = max(year) in holidays`... Is that not correct?

Comment: "populated by finding the holidays element that joins onto lastHolidayDestination" so no, not max

Comment: Ah. I assumed by "last" you were looking for the element in the array with the greatest year. In which case, you wouldn't need to store Florida separately, as this would be a derived view from the original dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simulate the join with array you can use flatten and filter combo:

```
val result = ds.withColumn("expl", explode(col("holidays")))
               .filter("lastHolidayDestination = expl.destination")
               .withColumn("lastHolidayYear", col("expl.year"))
               .drop("expl")
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Spark 3.0, you can first filter the array and then get the first element of the array with the following expression:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{element_at, filter, col}

val extractElementExpr = element_at(filter(col("myArrayColumnName"), myCondition), 1)
```

Where `"myArrayColumnName"` is the name of the column containing the array and `myCondition` is the condition, which is a `Column => Column` expression.

For your specific example, the code is:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, element_at, filter}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

val isLastHoliday = (c: Column) => c.getField("destination") === col("lastHolidayDestination")
val getLastHoliday = element_at(filter(col("holidays"), isLastHoliday), 1)

val result = df.withColumn("lastHolidayYear", getLastHoliday.getField("year"))
```

With this code, if your input dataframe contains the following values:

```
+------+----------------------+--------------------------------+
|name  |lastHolidayDestination|holidays                        |
+------+----------------------+--------------------------------+
|Ben   |Florida               |[[Florida, 2020], [Lille, 2019]]|
|Alice |Peru                  |[[Florida, 2020], [Lille, 2019]]|
|Robert|Lille                 |[[Florida, 2020], [Lille, 2019]]|
+------+----------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Output will be:

```
+------+----------------------+--------------------------------+---------------+
|name  |lastHolidayDestination|holidays                        |lastHolidayYear|
+------+----------------------+--------------------------------+---------------+
|Ben   |Florida               |[[Florida, 2020], [Lille, 2019]]|2020           |
|Alice |Peru                  |[[Florida, 2020], [Lille, 2019]]|null           |
|Robert|Lille                 |[[Florida, 2020], [Lille, 2019]]|2019           |
+------+----------------------+--------------------------------+---------------+
```